# How Can I Populate Dropdown Select Element using getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to populate dropdown select menu.
i need to get bankName and iINNo from this JSON

**My JSON :**

```
{"status":true,"message":"Request Completed","data":[{"id":1,"activeFlag":1,"bankName":"Union Bank of India","details":"Union Bank of India","iINNo":"607161","remarks":"","timestamp":"21/11/2016 16:00:00"},{"id":2,"activeFlag":1,"bankName":"Bank of India","details":"Bank of India","iINNo":"508505","remarks":"","timestamp":"21/11/2016 16:00:00"},],"statusCode":0}
```

**My Javacript :**

```
 let dropdown = $('#Bank');

dropdown.empty();

dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Bank</option>');
dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

const url = 'http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';

// Populate dropdown with list of provinces
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

  $.each(data, function (res, code) {
          console.info(res);
                  console.info(code);
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', value.iINNo).text(index.bankName)); 
    })
});
```

Comment: What does this question have to to with PHP?

Comment: You should also include a proper explanation of your issue. What actually happens when you run your code? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array with bank data is under the property `data` inside the JSON. So the trick is to loop over that property - right now you loop over the entire JSON response, including the status and message properties.

You will get the individual bank object as the second argument `item` and then you can access it's properties and append it to your dropdown:

```
$.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
    console.info('Bank Data: ', item);
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').text(item.bankName)); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
const banks = document.getElementById('banks');
banks.innerHTML = '<option selected="true" disabled>Select Bank</option>';

fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.allindiaapi.com/HMESEVAAEPS/GetBankDetails?tokenkey=KzhnBIUi1wuM97yizKJ07WB3YwPSykyX9CjB6C6O5LRyClZ9YZl9NcIk5f6Fjna4')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
 if(response.status){
   response.data.forEach(bank => {
     const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = bank.iINNo;
      option.innerContent = bank.bankName;
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="banks"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the data you need is in the `data` property of the `data` object, so you need to loop over `data.data`. In addition the properties of each object will be in the second argument of the handler function, `code` in your example. For example `code.bankName`.

However it's worth noting that the code can be tidied, and also have its performance improved by using `map()` to build a single string of `option` elements which you append to the DOM only once. Try this:

```js
let $dropdown = $('#Bank');
$dropdown.html('<option value="" disabled>Select Bank</option>').val('');

// AJAX commented for example only:
//$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  let data = {
    "status": true,
    "message": "Request Completed",
    "data": [{
      "id": 1,
      "activeFlag": 1,
      "bankName": "Union Bank of India",
      "details": "Union Bank of India",
      "iINNo": "607161",
      "remarks": "",
      "timestamp": "21/11/2016 16:00:00"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "activeFlag": 1,
      "bankName": "Bank of India",
      "details": "Bank of India",
      "iINNo": "508505",
      "remarks": "",
      "timestamp": "21/11/2016 16:00:00"
    }, ],
    "statusCode": 0
  }

  let html = data.data.map(bank => `<option value="${bank.iINNo}">${bank.bankName}</option>`);
  $dropdown.append(html);
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Bank"></select>
```